# Is there a way to make a PDO child object throw CustomException instead of PDOException?

Tags: php, exception, pdo

Is there a way to make a class such this one:

```
class DB extends PDO {}
```

(which for the record has just one method (the constructor) overloading the parent one so that we pass no parameters to the constructor and we connect via configuration file)

be able to throw in any case a custom `CustomException` like this:

```
throw new CustomException($e->getMessage(), 500, array($e->...));
```

with `$e` being an instance of the `PDOException` occurred, instead of the default `PDOException`, without wrapping all the methods within a try-catch block?

Comment: What would be a reason for this?

Comment: @Niko, long and pretty boring story. I have to have a centralized CustomException that should cover all the exception that my application is going to throw. Just trust me. I have to convert PDOException s into CustomException s before their use, I cannot do that after; And no, I cannot set the error mode of PDO as normal PHP error and catch them as normal warnings.

Comment: If you need to catch all exceptions at some point, you may want to consider just using `catch (Exception $e)` there. That catches PDOExceptions as well as CustomExceptions.

Comment: @Niko, But I want to be able to differentiate the behavior. I need PDOExceptions to throw CustomException s with code `123` for example. So that I'm still able to differentiate the type of the Exception but using my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how typesafe your code has to be (type hints vs duck typing):

You could write a class which does **not** extend PDO and use it as delegate via the  [__call](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method. Inside __call() you can catch the actual PDO exception and wrap it in your custom exception. So you still have to write a wrapper, but a rather short one.

Comment: What about PDOStatement, how should I manage that? We have to cover also those methods...

Comment: You can overwrite prepare() and return one more delegate Object with a single __call() Wrapper. Did you consider to simply catch PDOException at some point in an upper layer and wrap/re-throw it in as  CustomException?

Comment: yep, I did and it is not an option. It is possible to set an extension of PDOStatement but it gotta be a child of PDOStatement so the __call() won't work. I'll manage something else. If an idea comes to your mind let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

You can throw a custom Exception in your own methods. So if you over wrote each PDO method in your extended class, and made them look like this:

```
public function query($statement) {
    try {
        parent::query($statement);
    } catch (PDOException $exception) {
        throw new CustomException(whatever you want to do here);
    }
}
```

This way whenever PDO throws a PDO Exception, it will catch the exception and throw a custom exception of your own. You will have to keep in mind however that PDO uses some other classes like PDOStatement which can create it's own PDOExceptions which you can also overwrite. you can use as your statement class through PDO's method arguments.

Comment: I would also wrap the throwing of the Exception in its own method and call that for easy editing later.

Comment: -1 for not reading the question thoroughly - *"without wrapping all the methods within a try-catch block."*

Comment: @drrcknlsn he may have meant not having to wrap each method call when using an instance of the class, and not known the option of overwriting each method to put a try catch block within the class' methods...

Comment: No, I meant exactly this. But never mind. Thanks for the answer anyway. Just so that other people know, to make this works perfectly you have also to extend PDOStatement class and wrap all of its methods too. No a real deal if you follow the "Don't repeat yourself" rule.